# how can use ListView in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, listview

i already added "deprecated-react-native-listview". But when i added " import ListView from 'deprecated-react-native-listview';" in my program. it will show error.

the error below:
Could not find a declaration file for module 'deprecated-react-native-listview'. 'd:/react/MyApp/node_modules/deprecated-react-native-listview/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm i --save-dev @types/deprecated-react-native-listview` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'deprecated-react-native-listview';`

how to solve the problem? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of ListView use **Flatlist** builtin component of react native.

**Usage**

import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, View, FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, StatusBar } from 'react-native';

```
const DATA = [
  {
    id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
    title: 'First Item',
  },
  {
    id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63',
    title: 'Second Item',
  },
  {
    id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
    title: 'Third Item',
  },
];

const Item = ({ title }) => (
  <View style={styles.item}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
  </View>
);

const App = () => {
  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <Item title={item.title} />
  );

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight || 0,
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
    padding: 20,
    marginVertical: 8,
    marginHorizontal: 16,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 32,
  },
});

export default App;
```